# Prove $\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b\frac{x}{\sin x}dx\leqslant\frac{a+b}{\sin a+\sin b}$ $a,b\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2}),a<b$

Tags: calculus

For $a,b\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2}),a<b$, prove

$$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b\frac{x}{\sin x}dx\leqslant\frac{a+b}{\sin a+\sin b}.$$

By mean value theorem, there is $c\in(a,b)$ s.t.

$$\frac{c}{\sin c}=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b\frac{x}{\sin x}dx$$

I want to prove that

$$\frac{c}{\sin c}\leqslant\frac{a+b}{\sin a+\sin b}$$

for any $c\in (a,b)$. I am not sure if I am on the right track

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality), since $\frac{x}{\sin x}$ is convex on $[a,b]$, you have that $$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b\frac{x}{\sin x}\,dx\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{a}{\sin a}+\frac{b}{\sin b}\right).$$ So it's enough to prove the following:

$$\frac{a\sin b+b\sin a}{2\sin a\sin a b}\leq\frac{a+b}{\sin a+\sin b}\Leftrightarrow(a+b)\sin a\sin b+b\sin^2a+a\sin^2 b\leq2(a+b)\sin a\sin b\Leftrightarrow b\sin^2a+a\sin^2b\leq(a+b)\sin a\sin b\Leftrightarrow$$$$b\sin a(\sin b-\sin a)+a\sin b(\sin a-\sin b)\geq 0\Leftrightarrow(\sin b-\sin a)(b\sin a-a\sin b)\geq 0.$$ But, $\sin b-\sin a>0$, so it is enough to show that $$b\sin a\geq a\sin b\Leftrightarrow\frac{\sin a}{a}\geq\frac{\sin b}{b}.$$ But, this holds, since $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is decreasing in $[a,b]$.

Comment: thank you! this is quite elegant

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If $a=\pi/6$ and $b=\pi/3$ the right side is $(\sqrt{3}-1)\pi/2 \approx 1.1499.$
But $1 \in (\pi/6,\pi/3)$ with $1/\sin(1) \approx 1.18839.$ So another approach is needed.  I think using the value of $c$ of the mean value theorem for integrals, one doesn't know enough about where $c$ lies to get accurate enough information for an inequality such as this.